# No output when I run a particular vbs script under task scheduler

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, task, scheduler, wsh

When I run the follow bat wrapper that calls cpusage.vbs under 
task scheduler with the option "Run wether user is logged on or not" turned on.
I get EMPTY as output, otherwise it's fine.

Here is the wrapper:

```
@echo off
SET SERVER=c:\Logs
SET TOOLOC=c:\Tools

SET datestamp=%date:~-4%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-10,2%
SET timestamp=%datestamp%%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%
if %time:~0,2% LSS 10 SET timestamp=%datestamp%"0"%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%


echo %timestamp% >> %SERVER%\%COMPUTERNAME%-CPU_%datestamp%.log
cscript //NoLogo %TOOLOC%\cpusage.vbs >> %SERVER%\%COMPUTERNAME%-CPU_%datestamp%.log 2>&1
```

The cpusage.vbs can be found here: http://www.pastebin.ca/2677241.

Thanks,

Comment: Your problem is unrelated to the batch code, since it does write the VBScript output to the file just fine. You need to investigate why the variable `strCoreCPUsages` in your VBScript code ends up containing an empty string. Try adding `WScript.Echo objItem.Name` at the beginning of the 2nd `For Each` loop to see if you actually get an item with the name `_Total`.

Comment: Also, try running it with administrative privilege's under the task scheduler, if you have not tried that already.

Answer (score 0):

For CPU

```
wmic path Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOs_Processor get /format:list
wmic path Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOs_Processor get PercentProcessorTime /format:list
```

For your disk report

```
wmic logicaldisk get FreeSpace,size,mediatype /format:list
```

For your memory (I couldn't find your script so I'm just guessing on what you are using)

```
wmic os get TotalVisibleMemorySize, TotalVirtualMemorySize, TotalSwapSpaceSize, SizeStoredInPagingFiles, MaxProcessMemorySize, FreePhysical Memory, FreeSpaceInPagingFiles, FreeVirtualMemory /format:hform >mem.html&start "" mem.html
```

Answer (score -2):

Try enabling delayed expansion and using `FOR /F`:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%a in ('cscript //NoLogo "!TOOLOC!\cpusage.vbs" 2^>^&1') do (echo/%%a >> "!SERVER!\!COMPUTERNAME!-CPU_!datestamp!.log")
```

Comment: This will not help, since the issue is with the VBScript code, not with the batch script.

Comment: It worked for me, I've even used the VBScript code mentioned above on my own computer, and had no problems.

Comment: Again, the OP does *not* have a problem with the batch code. According to the problem description the task starts the batch script, the batch script starts the VBScript, the VBScript echoes `EMPTY`, and the batch script redirects that output to the log file. Delayed expansion on or off does not change anything about the output the VBScript generates.